# Primary and Replica dbs on Rails 4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mysql2

I'm implementing on Rails 4 a primary/replica dbs, simple `REST` implementations such as using a `POST` to always use the *primary* and `GET` for the *replica* won't work in this case since the app can potentially modify records on any given request (mark a notification as read, set the last login time of the user, etc.).

I thought about overriding the `ActiveRecord` *persistance* methods like this:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  def save(*)
    write_only { super }
  end

  def save!(*)
    write_only { super }
  end

  def delete
    write_only { super }
  end

  def destroy
    write_only { super }
  end

  def becomes(klass)
    write_only { super(klass) }
  end

  def becomes!(klass)
    write_only { super(klass) }
  end

  def update_columns(attributes)
    write_only { super(attributes) }
  end

  private

  def write_only
    begin
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection("#{Rails.env}_primary".to_sym)
      yield
    ensure
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection("#{Rails.env}_replica".to_sym)
    end
  end
end
```

From this every model just inherit from `ApplicationRecord` like:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  ...
end
```

This implementation works fine on most cases (specially on the rails console never found an issue), however I found that in some situations, I get errors such as: `Rails -- Exception: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: MySQL client is not connected: ROLLBACK`, specially when using `create`, `create!` (This is not always the case btw)

is there a better way?

**Note:** I didn't override the `create` methods since internally they call `save`, the same goes for others, however I've tried it and the app still fails.

Comment: I would be very careful with monkey patching these methods. Why are you not using a bullet proofed gem like Makara (https://github.com/instacart/makara)?

Comment: +1 to @ChristianBruckmayer's suggestion. An answer explaining the implementation like you ask may be educational, but using a gem would be the best bet. This is another popular option https://github.com/thiagopradi/octopus

Comment: Tnx @ChristianBruckmayer didn't knew that gem gonna try it out

Comment: Our Ruby on Rails reached end-of-life and is unsupported. Instead of adding such a complex, low-level feature to an old Rails app, I would focus on upgrading the application to the latest Ruby on Rails version. Apart from the security feature, improved speed, and more functionality, Ruby on Rails 6.1 has build-in [support for multiple databases](https://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2020/12/9/Rails-6-1-0-release/).